# Using Queryset for many-to-many in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

I'm trying to apply values from the admin dropdown function (query set). The below code works, but only for Foreign Keys.

If I try to apply this to a many-to-many field, I get a FieldError that says "only non-relations and foreign keys permitted".

```
def tag_Tagtest(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(tag=Tag.objects.get(name__iexact='BLAH_BLAH'), updated=timezone.now())
```

This is my attempt for ManyToMany:

-----models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ("Name", max_length=400)
    tag = models.ManyToMany (Tag, blank=True)


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tag_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

----admin.py

```
def TEST_M2M (self, request, queryset):
queryset = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name
```

How can I use the code above to apply to a many-to-many field?

Answer (score 1):

Django can't add M2M values to multiple objects at once, but you can loop over the queryset.

```
blahblah=Tag.objects.get(name__iexact='BLAH_BLAH')
for product in queryset:
     product.tag.add(blahblah)
```

Comment: As long as M2M relation is symmetrical, instead of adding tag to products, you can add products to tag: `Tag.objects.get(...).product_set.add(*list(queryset))`